# count number of file and number of lines in the file using NiFi Processors

Tags: apache-nifi

I collect data which is in csv format. I count the lines inside the csv files to have a total number of lines. for that I use the GetFile -> Merge -> CountText processors. I also want to count the number of csv files, to have a number as I collect the data.

I want to know how to count the number of files so that I can display the lines count and the number of files to collect.Thanks

Comment: If you are looking for the number of CSV files merged, then MergeContent processor creates an attribute as `merge.count` = `the number of FlowFiles that were merged into bundle`

Comment: Hi Vikramsinh Shinde, I don't see this attribute in the attributes created by MergeContent Processor. can you explain How can I get this attribute. Thanks

Comment: Observe attributes for any flowfile routed to `merged` relationship by `MergeContent` processor. Refer `Writes Attribute`  section here - https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeContent/

Comment: Are you able to find `merge.count` attribute?

Comment: Hi, Vikramsinh Shinde Yes I found a merge.count attribute in the CountText processor.